# It's passing intent to camera but not receiving the clicked pic but when I'm choosing gallery option it's receiving the selected picture

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to pass an intent for receiving picture from gallery or camera or file manager.It's passing intent successfully but not receiving picture but in case of gallery it's receiving the selected picture.

My Code :

```
private void choosePhotoFromGallery() {
    Intent pickIntent = new Intent();
    pickIntent.setType("image/*");
    pickIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    String pickTitle = "Take or select a photo";
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent, pickTitle);
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] { takePhotoIntent });
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 1);}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent    data) {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            try {



InputStream inputStream = getContentResolve().openInputStream(data.getData());
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                   imgView.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Logger.log(e.getMessage());
            }
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you taken all Permissions related to camera? And also runtime permissions that are required for android M onwards?

Comment: @kapsym I added permissions but it still not receiving image

Comment: I added my answer below. Have a look and let me know if you still face issues.

Comment: @kapsyam sir how to detect path inside onActivityResult

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is this:

```
data.getData()
```

You need to get the extra from the returned Intent like this:

```
data.getExtras().get("data");
```

So your InputStream should be like -

```
InputStream inputStream = getContentResolve().openInputStream(data.getExtras().get("data"));
```

UPDATE 1:

You can also modify your approach to do it this way by creating a file first and then passing the file URI to that intent. This saves you from device specific issues that you might face in previous method. -

```
 Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
 if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                            // Create the File where the photo should go
       File photoFile = null;
       try {
             photoFile = createImageFile();
           } catch (IOException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
           }
      // Continue only if the File was successfully created
      if (photoFile != null) {

            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1734);
      }
 }

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      if (requestCode==1734 && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
           BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;
        int scale = 1;
        while (options.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                && options.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale *= 2;
        options.inSampleSize = scale;
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
     }
}

// This is just a method to create a File with current timestamp in name
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    File image=null;
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(null);
        if (!storageDir.exists()) {
            storageDir.mkdir();
        }
        image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    }
    return image;

}
```

Comment: Which device are you using for test?

Comment: @SrinivasNahak added an updated answer that i am using in my code and it works fine.

Comment: @kapsyam sir how to detect path inside onActivityResult

Comment: Just declare a class level variable and assign it the same value as that of file path at the time of calling the intent

Comment: Use mCurrentPhotoPath in on Activity result instead of path. That's my copy mistake. This the same variable I set in createImageFile method. Declare mCurrentPhotoPath as class level variable before oncreate.